# how get access to host mysql database from my snap app

Tags: mysql, node.js, snapcraft, snap

I'm building a nodejs app using sequalize to handle the mysql database. Now I'm trying to snap that app and I found an error connecting to mysql from the snap service. Which should be the correct way of snapping a nodejs app and get access to mysql server installed on the host.